# window.scrollTo unreliable on page load

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've got a polymer element that displays a timestamp in a human-friendly format. I want the text of the timestamp to be a permalink that will scroll the browser to the element on page load. Regular HTML anchors apparently aren't supported in shadow DOM. This solution sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work. I'm guessing its unreliability has something to do with the fact that the page is loading still, but I can't figure out how to fix it. I have tried putting the scrollTo command in ready(), DOMReady(), and attached() and can't seem to get it to work consistently no matter where it is. I have tried using the async() command to delay the call, but it still doesn't work consistently. Please forgive me that this example is not a working code snippet but I wasn't sure how to get it working when it doesn't occupy the entire window (like in codepen or something).

```
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../elements/momentjs.html">

<polymer-element name="time-ago" attributes="timestamp anchorId">
  <template>
    <a href="{{permalink}}" on-click="{{scrollToSelf}}" title="{{timestamp | unitToFullDateTime}}">{{timeAgo}}</a>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('time-ago', {
      ready: function() {
        var self = this;
        var url = document.URL.replace(/#.*\/?$/, "");
        self.permalink = url + '#anchorid=' + encodeURIComponent(self.anchorId);
        var periodicUpdater = function () {
          self.timeAgo = moment.unix(self.timestamp / 1000.0).fromNow();
          self.async(function() {
            periodicUpdater();
          }, null, 10000);
        };
        periodicUpdater();
      },
      attached: function () {
        var self = this;
        var match = /#anchorid=(.*)$/.exec(document.URL);
        if (match) {
          var anchorId = match[1];
          if (anchorId === self.anchorId) {
            self.scrollToSelf();
          }
        }
      },
      scrollToSelf: function () {
        var self = this;
        window.scrollTo(0, self.offsetTop - 20);
      },
      unitToFullDateTime: function () {
        return moment.unix(arguments[0] / 1000.0).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified solution with all the `moment.js` logic stripped out and with a hardcoded id of the element to scroll to. You should be able to adapt it to use a dynamic element id, but that doesn't really work well within the context of a code snippet.

It relies on [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView), and is similar to something that the [`<core-doc-page>` element does](https://github.com/Polymer/core-doc-viewer/blob/master/elements/core-doc-page.html#L172).

```html
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="time-ago">
  <template>
    <div id="elementToScrollTo">
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      domReady: function() {
        this.$.elementToScrollTo.scrollIntoView();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<div class="filler" style="height: 5000px;">Filler</div>
<time-ago>A long time ago!</time-ago>
```

Comment: Thanks @jeff-posnick. for some weird reason this only works half the time on Chrome. Some refreshes work and some don't. It almost seems like it is not quite through rendering some elements when it gets called and so it ends up either in some odd place or doesn't run at all.